# Обьясните код Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скажите почему если не написать IF ELSE то код не получиться и буден работать бесконечно?
Оригинальный код

```
def calculateSum(num):
    if num:
        return num + calculateSum(num-1)
    else:
        return 0

res = calculateSum(10)
print(res)
```

И код который спрашиваю

```
def calculateSum(num):
     return num + calculateSum(num-1)
   
res = calculateSum(10)
print(res)
```

Comment: Если не написать else, то функция будет вызывать сама себя постоянно. Вызвала раз себя, следующая вызвала себя снова и так далее... Но нам надо же остановить этот бессконечный цикл, вот и мы написали else. Т.е. когда num будет False, т.е. 0, то последняя вызванная функция вернет 0, следовательно все следующие будут возвращать переданный им num + предыдущее значение начиная от 0 + 1 и идя далее 1 + 2 и тд.

Comment: А окей, я не знал что когда 0 то False, я новый просто. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Легко проверить, `bool(0) -> False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это рекурсия: функция, которая вызывает сама себя. Она Прекратит вызывать саму себя в 2-х случаях: переполнение стека вызовов (условный мешок, в который можно положить несколько вещей в одном порядке, но доставать эти условные вещи нужно только в обратном порядке. При переполнении стека вызовов программа просто зависнет) , или точка выхода из рекурсии.

Оператор else в данном случае остановит вызов рекурсии.